# Extracting a key-value pair from inside a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, keyvaluepair

I have the following string:

```
string myString = "{'gridObject':'[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]'}";
```

How do I process this into an object so that I can do this:

```
charts[0]     //=> [1,2,3,4]
charts[0][1]  //=> 2
```

If I can convert it to this object, even better:

```
public class gridObject {

    public int datarow   {get; set;}
    public int datacol   {get; set;}
    public int datasizex {get; set;}
    public int datasizey {get; set;}

}
```

Comment: The big problem you've got here is that you've got an obvious delimiter (the comma) at two levels in your input - separating the numbers **and** separating the sets of numbers. How much control do you have over the format of this data? Can you get it changed?

Comment: What have you tried? The outer object looks like JSON, so the value of the `gridObject` can be parsed separately.

Comment: ChrisF: I have full control over the format. I can change the delimiters and everything else.

Comment: You can use a JSON parsing library: once for the `myString` string itself, and then again on the string, by wrapping `[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]` with extra square brackets to ensure it is a properly formed JSON string (of a 2D array).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165

Comment: _" I have full control over the format"_ - make it fully valid JSON with arrays and all, then the parsing is trivial.

Comment: OK, I can encode the data on the front-end like this: `{"chartObjects":[{"datarow":"1","datacol":"2","datasizex":"3","datasizey":"4"},{"datarow":"5","datacol":"6","datasizex":"7","datasize":"8"}]}`. JSLint says that's valid JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I would do.

Create your classes first,

```
public class GridObject
{
    public int datarow { get; set; }
    public int datacol { get; set; }
    public int datasizex { get; set; }
    public int datasizey { get; set; }
}

public class GridObjectCollection
{
    public GridObject[] GridObjects { get; set; }
}
```

Then, to see what JSON you need, serialize it once: (JsonConvert is part of [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), you can get it with NuGet)

```
GridObjectCollection gridObjects = new GridObjectCollection();
gridObjects.GridObjects = new GridObject[]
{
    new GridObject() { datacol = 1, datarow = 2, datasizex = 3, datasizey = 4 },
    new GridObject() { datacol = 5, datarow = 6, datasizex = 7, datasizey = 8 }
};

Console.WriteLine
(
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject
    (
        gridObjects,
        new JsonSerializerSettings() { Formatting = Formatting.Indented }
    )
);
```

Here you can see that the valid JSON content which will produce these classes when deserialized is like:

```
{
  "GridObjects": [
    {
      "datarow": 2,
      "datacol": 1,
      "datasizex": 3,
      "datasizey": 4
    },
    {
      "datarow": 6,
      "datacol": 5,
      "datasizex": 7,
      "datasizey": 8
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, just try a deserialization just to make sure:

```
var f = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GridObjectCollection>
(
    "{'GridObjects':[{'datarow':2,'datacol':1,'datasizex':3,'datasizey':4},{'datarow':6,'datacol':5,'datasizex':7,'datasizey':8}]}"
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Unrelated question: is there a "sandbox" environment I can use to quickly test stuff like this without actually implementing it in my project and running the project? I'm looking for something like the browser's javascript console, in which you can just type statements and see how they get evaluated. I use Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: +1 to @LucMorin. You can also copy your json to clipboard and in Visual Studio, in a class window, Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes

Comment: @OguzOzgul Ahhh... nifty :)

Comment: @LucMorin That would have saved me hours if I knew that before, it was there, hidden in the Edit menu since the release of VS 2012 :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
public static gridObject[] Parse(string str)
{
    int first = str.IndexOf("[");

    int last = str.LastIndexOf("]");

    str = str.Substring(first, last - first + 1);

    string[] big_parts = str.Split(new string[] {"[", "],[", "]"} , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


    return big_parts.Select(x =>
    {
        string[] small_parts = x.Split(',');

        return new gridObject()
        {
            datarow = Convert.ToInt32(small_parts[0]),
            datacol = Convert.ToInt32(small_parts[1]),
            datasizex = Convert.ToInt32(small_parts[2]),
            datasizey = Convert.ToInt32(small_parts[3]),

        };
    }).ToArray();
}
```

It first searches for the the first `[` and the last `]` and trims anything before `[` and after `]`.

Then, it splits the string based on `[`, `],[`, `]`.

This will give us `1,2,3,4` and `5,6,7,8` for your example.

Then for each one of them, we split based on `,` and convert the results into a `gridObject` object.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try. I'm new to C# so I really appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Done with custom parsing:

```
public class GridObject
{
    public int datarow { get; set; }
    public int datacol { get; set; }
    public int datasizex { get; set; }
    public int datasizey { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// MySuperObject class which holds a reference to inner array of integers
/// </summary>
public class MySuperObject
{
    public List<int> Items { get; set; } // Inner array of list of integers

    public MySuperObject()
    {
        Items = new List<int>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Need to override ToString to return something like "[1,2,3,4]"
        var result = "";
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            if (result.Length > 0)
                result += ",";
            result += item.ToString();
        }
        return string.Format("[{0}]", result);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to generate GridObject from existing set of integers
    /// </summary>
    public GridObject GetGridObject()
    {
        var result = new GridObject();
        if (Items.Count >= 1) result.datarow = Items[0];
        if (Items.Count >= 2) result.datacol = Items[1];
        if (Items.Count >= 3) result.datasizex = Items[2];
        if (Items.Count >= 4) result.datasizey = Items[3];
        return result;
    }
}

// Parse functions
public List<MySuperObject> Parse(string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        throw new ArgumentException("value cannot be null or empty!", "value");

    var result = new List<MySuperObject>();

    // First get the indexes of first [ and last ]
    var idxStart = value.IndexOf("[");
    var idxEnd = value.LastIndexOf("]");
    // Check validity
    if (idxStart < 0 || idxEnd < 0 || idxEnd <= idxStart)
        return result; // Return empty list

    value = value.Substring(idxStart, idxEnd - idxStart + 1).Trim();

    // Split by [] after replacing spaces with empty strings (and removing first and last [ and ])
    var arr = value.Replace(" ", "").Trim('[',']').Split(new[] { "],[" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (var str in arr)
    {
        // Construct list of integers with a help of LINQ
        var nums = str.Split(',').Select(t => Convert.ToInt32(t)).ToList();

        // Create and add MySuperObject to existing list which will be returned
        result.Add(new MySuperObject
        {
            Items = new List<int>(nums),
        });
    }

    return result;
}
```

And here is the usage of such parsing:

```
var myString = "{'gridObject':'[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]'}";
var value = Parse(myString);
// Get all grid objects
var allGridObjects = value.Select(t => t.GetGridObject()).ToList();
```

Of course, this could need a little bit more of error checking but basically, this MySuperObject is used to use any number of integers you desire, while providing you with a helper method of "GetGridObject" to fill you grid object with appropriate numbers from array of numbers.